# Saw a website scraping contents of SharePoint Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, legal, licensing, attribution, copyright-infringement

I just stumbled upon this website:

```
http://meta.sharepoint.readquestion.com/
```

And this site has scrapped almost all the contents of SharePoint Meta and **it comes on Google Search as well**. Is this something to be reported to Stack Exchange HQ?